# Half circle background CSS

Tags: css, background

I am having a problem to create a background with CSS like the image below. 
[image]

Here is my code i have tried

```
<style> 
#example1 {
    border: 2px solid red;
    background: green;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    border-top: 0px;

}
</style>

<div id="example1">
<p>test</p>
</div>
```

This should be must work with different window size (responsive). The background also 100% in width always. Seeking help to create this background. Any kind of help appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: so where is your code or do you think we will do the work for you?

Comment: I forgot to add my code. code added. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
</div>
<div class="bg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bg {
  width:100%;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-top:-130px;
}
```